# C++ appcrash USER32.dll

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

```
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: program.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 537374b6
  Fault Module Name: USER32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.16384
  Fault Module Timestamp: 52157ca5
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000949d
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1049
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: 3a20
  Additional Information 4: 3a20a93c34687143a5bf7d33f1cf3ccc
```

Im trying to make C++ winapi program, the its only function is to draw a window with a button that toggles cursor move and click, but right after window is shown, the app crashes before able to do something. In window procedure i have only WM_COMMAND, WM_DESTROY and default return DefWindowProc() cases. The WinMain function code:

```
    WNDCLASSEX wcx;
    int X, Y;
    MSG msg;
    RECT srect;

    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &srect);
    X = srect.right;
    Y = srect.bottom;

    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DROPSHADOW;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = MainProc;
    wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcx.hInstance = hinst;
    wcx.hIcon = 0;
    wcx.hCursor = 0;
    wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcx.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wcx.lpszClassName = L"wcname";
    wcx.hIconSm = 0;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcx)){
        MessageBox(0, L".", L"RegisterClass failed", 0);
        return 1;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        L"wcname",
        L"off",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        X / 2 - 112,
        Y / 2 - 40,
        224,
        80,
        0,
        0,
        hinst,
        0
    );

    if (!hwnd){
        MessageBox(0, L".", L"CreateWindow failed", 0);
        return 1;
    }

    GetClientRect(hwnd, &srect);
    X = srect.right;
    Y = srect.bottom;

    btn = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        L"button",
        L"Turn on",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
        0, 0,
        X, Y,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU)BTN,
        hinst,
        0
    );

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(0, hwnd, 0, 0)){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
```

The HWNDs are global variables, BTN and MAIN are macros.

Comment: If you run in a debugger, it will stop at the place of the crash, letting you examine values of variables, and check (and walk up) the function call stack. Do that to find where (in your code) it crashes, and check values to see if you can figure out why.

Comment: Also, compile at the maximum warning level (`/W4`). You might be doing something obviously wrong that the compiler can detect.

Comment: I used Beep(300, 300); as a debugger and found out that problem is after UpdateWindow(hwnd). I tried to paste beep into GetMessage loop but app crashes before beep can make a sound. I have no idea what to do with this

Comment: You have an access violation at a very low memory address. Likely to be an uninitialized variable or NULL-pointer dereference.

Comment: I forgot the msg variable in GetMessage function. Many thanks for the answers, very stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lpMsg` argument to GetMessage is not allowed to be NULL (0).

This call:

```
while (GetMessage(0, hwnd, 0, 0))
```

Needs to be:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0))
```